# How to create an add-able dropdown using html similar to what we use in the jira while adding the component?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create an add-able dropdown using HTML similar to what we use in the Jira while adding the component/s. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Example:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by add-able dropdown?

Comment: @NickvanderWaal When you type in to search the item you looking for in the dropdown and you don't find it, you can add at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This needs some styling and you will need to change the way some of the elements are selected but this is the basic JavaScript concept:

```js
const dropdownOptions = [
  "qwert",
  "scdfvgbh",
  "cdrdh",
  "sdsrg",
  "sgfbrynhybgdfv",
  "847ht4r"
];


//selects the div
const container = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

//creates elements
dropdownOptions.forEach(name => {
  const element = document.createElement("p");
  element.innerHTML = name;
  container.appendChild(element);
});

//selects the input
const input = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  //selects every element in the div
  const elements = container.children;

  //loop through dropdown options
  for (let i = 0, l = elements.length; i < l; i++) {

    //checks if the value of the input is contained in the dropdown option
    if (elements[i].innerHTML.includes(input.value)) {
      elements[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      elements[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 150px;
}

div {
  width: 156px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div>p {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <input type="text" />
  <div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```